# Trouble while using .svg file in React.js code

Tags: css, reactjs, image, user-interface, svg

I am trying to use illustration in my react project (https://storyset.com/illustration/market-launch/pana/animate)
[illustration image which I trying to use in my code https://i.stack.imgur.com/AQr8P.png

I choose SVG and CSS I got long coded .svg file, Can anyone help me, how can I use that file of SVG  in my react code

[.svg file which I trying to access](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u2wzH.png)

Answer (score 0):

Import that file in location where you want to use it using:

import { ReactComponent as NameOfYourSvg } from "./yoursvg.svg"

Replace NameOfYourSvg with name that you want to use for it, it must start with capital letter.

After that just use svg in your code like that:

```
<div>
<NameOfYourSvg />
<div>
```